# Mongoose function returning before Promise resolved

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

```
mongoCheckFile = async (fileData) => {
try {
 let offerIdsValues = [];
 //Extract all fileIds from CSV
 fileData.data.forEach((element, idx, fileData) => {
   fileIdsInCsv.push(`${element.fileId}`)
 });

fileData.fileOffers.forEach(element => {
  offerIdsValues.push(element.id);
});

let matchingClickDocs = [];

//The following functions are not waited for before returning
await Click.find({ 
  $and: [ {fileId: { $in: fileIdsInCsv} }, { fileId: {$in: offerIdsValues} } ] 
}).populate('furtherInfo').exec(async (error, clicks) =>  {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
     await Promise.all(clicks.map(async (click) => {
       const furtherDatas = await furtherData.findOne({ fileId: click.fileId });
       if (furtherDatas) {
         click.furtherInfo = furtherDatas;
         await click.save();
         matchingClickDocs.push(click);
        //this pushes correct values and creates correct array.
       }
     }));
     console.log(matchingClickDocs.length, 'first')
    // This returns after global function  with correct val
  }
  console.log(matchingClickDocs.length, 'second')
    // This returns after above  with correct val
  });
console.log( matchingClickDocs.length, 'third')
// Returns first with incorrect Val.
  }
  catch (err) {
    return (err);
  }
};
```

This function returns before the promise returns its array.
I have console.logged the output as I run through and its all good until it comes to returning it.
I've hit a brick wall trying to return these values before the function returns.
I guess its a problem with the global function not awaiting the promises at the end.
I've tried a few different implementations but keep getting stuck on it.

Comment: Add a `return` before 1. `await Click.find` 2. `await Promise.all`

Comment: So literally —— return await Click.find?

Comment: @Yousaf this seems to return undefined

Comment: What are you returning from the function? Maybe you forgot to return `matchingClickDocs`?!

Comment: I did add returns but they did not return :) 

Its just promise hell I guess.